# Regex to add # after domain name

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need a regex to change the url from

```
http://example.com/page > https://example.com/#/page
```

and

```
https://example.com/page > https://example.com/#/page
```

I created this one and I added in 80 and 443 port virtualhosts apache and first redirect works but the second one doesn't

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*%23.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}#%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get even more complicated, depending what you are looking for but here is an example match.

```
^(https?:\/\/[^\/]+)\/?(.*)
```

Which you would replace with $1/#$2/

https://regex101.com/r/mAES1b/3

Comment: $1/#/$2 this is what I need but I don't know how to put this in apache

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteCond failed because You can not manipulate # (fregment) using rewriteRule as it's not sent to the server. If you want to redirect to # you can use this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^ /#%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

NE flag is important otherwise apache converts # into %23

Comment: Works from http but from https I'm redirected on     https://example.com/#/ and the browser says "The page isn’t redirecting properly"

Comment: Ok ,i udated the code. Clear you browser cache before testing.

Comment: I browse in incognito and now with the change doesn't work neither from http

Comment: "The page isn’t redirecting properly" and I'm redirected to example.com/#/

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. It works but It looks like its forcing the # in the URL. I need a redirection because the page is displayed only if the URL you entered contain /#/